# How to add full page bottom tabs on Buddypress/BuddyBoss?

Tags: wordpress, tabs, buddypress, buddyboss

I have a website with the BuddyBoss platform and the BuddyBoss theme. Im wanting to add tabs to the main page at the very bottom on the mobile view. They would be like “Feed” “Photos” etc. This will give users the ability to move about the site without having to use menu all the time. My question is, where would I start to accomplish this? Would I just edit the child theme and wrap the site? If so, where specifically in the template would this be accomplished? Id only want it on the main page and sections, not necessarily every page.